# Is there any revision document conserve software recommend?

Tags: file-management

Is there any revision document conserve software recommend?

My requirement:

I have a text file, it changes frequently by several admins, I want every change should have a content commit for brief conclusion, and I also can rollback to special version.

is there any recommend software like this?

---

I want a GUI software. web GUI better. this is no OS restrictions.
If cannot fit, there is a software based on macOS or Windows all can be ok.

Comment: Mind to include what OS it should run on, whether it should be GUI based or CLI, and in case of paid software, how much you'd be willing to spend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your "text" file is plain text, markdown or ReStructuredText you can use any of git, mercurial or other source control software. For a nice GUI that integrates with File Explorer there are several "Tortoise" implementations such as [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), [TortoiseHg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TortoiseHg), etc. both are:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross platform Windows, Linux, OS-X
- Provide both GUI & Command line interfaces

Personally I prefer TortoiseHg/Mercurial but git is very popular and easier to find hosting solutions for.

Any good version control system will allow you to track changes, see who made them, be able to revert them, be able to tag important ones, etc.